# Line number in a C++ istream?

Tags: c++, iostream

Suppose I'm reading tokens from a `std::istream`. What is a good way to know the number of newlines that have been read from the stream? This is for the purpose of error reporting in a parser. I don't want to use `std::getline` to read input.

Here is a test case. I am looking for something functionally similar to `GetLineNumber`, which in this case would return the line number of the last read token.

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "1 \n 2 \n 3 \n";

int x;
while (ss >> x) {
    std::cout << "Line " << GetLineNumber(ss) << ": " << x << std::endl;
}
```

The output to this example should be:

```
Line 1: 1
Line 2: 2
Line 3: 3
```

Comment: `std::istream` doesn't track that information.  If you want line numbers, you'll have to keep track of lines yourself.

Comment: What would be a good way to hook into a stream to get that information, without having to rewrite the stream interface?

Comment: @NicolasLouisGuillemot: there is no *good* way to hook into that, but you can always just use your own line-counting stream buffer. instead of delving down to that lower level you should use a higher level stream interface, internally implemented via `getline`. that's both for clarity and efficiency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a filtering streambuf, and keep count there:

```
class LineNumberStreambuf : public std::streambuf
{
    std::streambuf* mySource;
    std::istream* myOwner;
    bool myIsAtStartOfLine;
    int myLineNumber;

    char myBuffer;
protected:
    int underflow()
    {
        int ch = mySource->sbumpc();
        if ( ch != EOF ) {
            myBuffer = ch;
            setg( &myBuffer, &myBuffer, &myBuffer + 1 );
            if ( myIsAtStartOfLine ) {
                ++ myLineNumber;
            }
            myIsAtStartOfLine = myBuffer == '\n';
        }
        return ch;
    }
public:
    LineNumberStreambuf( std::streambuf* source )
        : mySource( source )
        , myOwner( nullptr )
        , myIsAtStartOfLine( true )
        , myLineNumber( 0 )
    {
    }
    LineNumberStreambuf( std::istream& owner )
        : mySource( owner.rdbuf() )
        , myOwner( &owner )
        , myIsAtStartOfLine( true )
        , myLineNumber( 0 )
    {
        myOwner->rdbuf( this );
    }
    ~LineNumberStreambuf()
    {
        if ( myOwner != nullptr ) {
            myOwner.rdbuf( mySource );
        }
    }
    int lineNumber() const
    {
        return myLineNumber;
    }
};
```

Just insert this into your input:

```
LineNumberStreambuf ln( std::cin );
//  ...
std::cerr << "Error (" << ln.lineNumber << "): ..." << std::endl;
```

Note that line numbers will only reflect the input which takes
place through the streambuf.

Comment: @Alf No big effort.  A long time ago, I was using filtering streambufs which managed several files, and so had the need for them to manage file name and line number; I just extracted the relevant code.  (And I can assure you that without actually having had the experience in using them, the necessity of using the `myIsAtStartOfLine` member wouldn't have occurred to me.)

Comment: If this class overrides `underflow`, why does it use `sbumpc` and `setg` instead of calling through to the superclass's `underflow` method?  (Please excuse my ignorance; I'm kind of intimidated by the internals of iostreams...)

Comment: If this extends `streambuf`, why does it also contain a `streambuf`? Why not just use `this` in place of `mySource`?