# istream tellg() returns -1 when applying a streambuffer filter

Tags: c++, redirect, istream

I want to keep track of the linenumber in a istream and therefore wanted to use a streambuffer filter:

```
class LineNumberStreambuf : public std::streambuf
{
    std::streambuf* mySource;
    std::istream* myOwner;
    bool myIsAtStartOfLine;
    int myLineNumber;

    char myBuffer;
protected:
    int underflow()
    {
        int ch = mySource->sbumpc();
        if ( ch != EOF ) {
            myBuffer = ch;
            setg( &myBuffer, &myBuffer, &myBuffer + 1 );
            if ( myIsAtStartOfLine ) {
                ++ myLineNumber;
            }
            myIsAtStartOfLine = myBuffer == '\n';
        }
        return ch;
    }
public:
    LineNumberStreambuf( std::streambuf* source )
        : mySource( source )
        , myOwner( nullptr )
        , myIsAtStartOfLine( true )
        , myLineNumber( 0 )
    {
    }
    LineNumberStreambuf( std::istream& owner )
        : mySource( owner.rdbuf() )
        , myOwner( &owner )
        , myIsAtStartOfLine( true )
        , myLineNumber( 0 )
    {
        myOwner->rdbuf( this );
    }
    ~LineNumberStreambuf()
    {
        if ( myOwner != nullptr ) {
            myOwner.rdbuf( mySource );
        }
    }
    int lineNumber() const
    {
        return myLineNumber;
    }
};
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24861313/7483073

When i try to read istreams current position via tellg() it fails after applying the stream buffer filter:

```
    int main()
    {
        std::istringstream input("i am a dummy test string");
        std::cout << input.tellg() << std::endl; //prints 0
        char c;
        input >> c;
        std::cout << input.tellg() << std::endl; //prints 1
        LineNumberStreambuf ln(input);
        std::cout << input.tellg() << std::endl; //prints -1 ??
        return 0;
    }
```

Edit:

I still couldn't find out why tellg() returns -1 after redirecting the streambuffer. The strange thing is that reading from istream is still possible. How can this be, if tellg() returns an invalid position?

Comment: What is `bnf`? What is its contents? What is `LineNumberStreambuf` and what does its constructor do?

Comment: bnf is a normal string like "foo bar". LineNumberStreambuf is a class from the link. i added its sourcecode to my question.